# Libgdx detect touch on a specific object (while moving)

Tags: libgdx, touch, screen

I have a class (I'll call it with letter "A") and class B.

A is the object (as a character) and B is the rendering class which have the aim to show A.

I am looking for a way to detect when A is pressed, with normal InputProcessor I can't because it detect touch in the entire screen, I only want detect touch over the object. If I check touch position and "A" position it doesn't work because the object is moving and the values aren't so precise

How to solve?

**this didn't solve for me** :[Efficient way of detecting a touched object in a game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/efficient-way-of-detecting-a-touched-object-in-a-game). Here is explained "what to do" and not "how to do"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way of detecting a touched object in a game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/efficient-way-of-detecting-a-touched-object-in-a-game)

Comment: @Pip It didn't help me

Comment: @user65825 In what way are the existing answers there insufficient? You could start a [bounty](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to raise attention to it once you have 75 rep, but this question still looks pretty close to that one to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is assign a listener to the Actor (I assume you are using these). This is as simple as (if you are trying to detect clicks):

```
myActor.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    public void clicked(args) {....
});
```

Then put whatever you want to happen in that `clicked` method. Make sure your game's input processor is that Stage! (`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myStage)`)

Comment: I don't use Actor

Comment: @user65825 I would recommend using [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d), if you aren't too far along. But I can elaborate on this answer to cater toward non-Scene2D users if you want, just let me know.

Comment: I am going to use this and I'll let you know the result. For now this is the best answer

Comment: I did what you said but it doesn't work, my touch isn't detected.  http://pastebin.com/4tfUnWZs

Comment: @user65825 You haven't set your actor's [size](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setSize-float-float-) or [position](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setPosition-float-float-) (although the default is 0, 0 so your current implementation can get away with that).

Comment: Should It be correct? 

        this.setSize(radius,radius);
        this.setPosition(position.x,position.y);   I put this code before addListener but it doesn't work

Comment: @user65825 Well, your radius is hardly your full width/height, but it should work (albeit not perfectly). In your actor's draw method can you change the `batch.draw` call to `batch.draw(tex, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight())`? Because right now you are drawing the circle at `0, 0` even if it is not actually there.

Comment: I changed as you said but now touch is detected in my circle and in another part of the screen which is the right and down quadrant

Comment: Can you edit your question and maybe add a picture of that and your updated code?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100751/libgdx-actor-touch-undetected